# Getting an error with oracle bulkcopy

Tags: c#

```
using System.Data;   
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
//using System.OracleBulkCopy;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
       // try
        {
            string path = string.Concat(("c:\\" + FileUpload1.FileName));
           FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);




            string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path);
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = excelConnectionString;
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);
            connection.Open();

            DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();


             OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection (@"Data Source=test1;User ID=TEST;Password=RAM");


             OracelBulkCopy bulkInsert = new OracelBulkCopy(con);
            bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "emp1";
            bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);
             Label1.Text = "task over";
        }
       //  catch(Exception ex)
        {
        // Label1.Text = ex.Message; 

    }
}

}
}
```

getting an error  Error

> 1   The type or namespace name 'OracelBulkCopy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

help me out this.
thanks in advance

Comment: trying to send a data from excel to  oracle data base

Comment: why you comment your namespace `using System.OracleBulkCopy;`

Comment: If I uncomment also i am getting the same error

Comment: any other answers please

Comment: Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' to 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader'